# Simple HQL/sql query..need assistance?

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate, hql

I have 2 tables (entity) a person entity and a vacation entity. One person can have many vacations.

What I'm trying to do is the following query:

Select all the persons period!, but for the persons who have a vacations, I want to fetch all of the persons vacations which have a condition , lest just say `startDate` is between something.

Just to be clear no matter the constraints on the vacations I still want to get all the persons.this is my current HQL query:

```
select distinct p 
from Person as p 
left join fetch p.vacations as v 
where v.startDate between '2011-07-01' and '2011-07-30'
```

The problem with it is that it constraint my persons an returns only the ones who have a vacation that respects the condition....Can someone help please?

I have no problem if someone can tell me this in native SQL

UPDATE Resolved in native SQL thanks to @Quasdunk:

```
SELECT * 
FROM person as p 
LEFT JOIN 
     (SELECT * FROM vacation
      WHERE startDate BETWEEN '2011-08-01' AND '2011-08-30') as v ON v.person_id = p.id
```

My new problem is how to convert it to an HQL query so I can fetch the vacations for each person, and the persons to be distinct (the conditions remain the same).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In native SQL this would be:

```
SELECT * 
FROM person 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * 
           FROM vacations 
           WHERE startDate BETWEEN '2011-07-01' AND '2011-07-30')
```

untested, but you get the idea :)

Comment: @Alexx What exactly is not working? Are the table names correct? Is the person-foreign-key in vacations named the same as in person (otherwise you have to join...on)?

Comment: You are mixing columns from both person and vacation and returning way more rows. Like select * from person p where person_id in (select person_id from vacations where ...) or person_id not in (select person_id from vacations)

Comment: @Udo Fholl That's how I understand the question. He wants to have ALL persons, and IF they were on vacation during that time it's supposed to select some vacation-fields. So joining all persons with a subset of vacation seems quite appropriate to me.

Comment: @Quasdunk: I just understood him in another way. All the persons who has no vacation. And all the persons with a vacation in a period. I might be mistaken thou.

Comment: Every derived table must have its own alias - this is the error i get ..and i`m not quite good in sql

Comment: @Alexx So give them aliases ;) `SELECT * FROM person as p LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM vacation as v_subset WHERE v_subset.startDate ...) as v`

Comment: @Quasdunk: it worked ..(see update) but now i`m trying to convert it to HQL fetching the vacations and the persons to be distinct ..

Comment: @Alexx Sorry, I've never worked with HQL, so I can't tell how to translate that :) But concerning the distinction, you can simply put a `distinct` after the first `select` like you did in your own approach.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following,

`select p.*, v.* from PERSON p LEFT JOIN VACATION v
on (p.id = v.p_id)
where v.startDate between '2011-07-21' and '2011-07-22'`

Hope this works for you.

Comment: sorry ...but its the same query as the one i posted ...only is sql not hql..thx for the help though

Comment: Hey Alex, I kinda tested it on a sample data. I thought you were fine with native sql too. Hence, the output in sql. Not sure why the HQL version shows different data. Perhaps, you could include the explain plan, or a sample data and the output you get from HQL execution.

Comment: sorry for the late answer but like i said before ..it does not do what i want him to do ...it returns only the persons who have a vacation

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use functions to achieve it:

```
select p from Person p 
where p.vacations.size = 0 
or (minelement(p.vacations) > '2011-07-01' 
    and 
    maxelement(p.vacations) < '2011-07-30')
```

Those dates might be actually a Date type. Depending of the type.

Try

```
select p from Person p 
where p.vacations.size = 0 
or (p.vacations.startDate > '2011-07-01' 
    and 
    p.vacations.endDate < '2011-07-30')
```

You should also take a look at [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-expressions)

Answer (score 0):

In plain (My)SQL it would look like this:

```
select distinct p.* from person p
left join vacations v on p.id = v.person_id 
where v.id is null or.v.start_date between '2011-07-01' and '2011-07-30'
```

In HQL this will probably be (not tested)

```
select distinct p from Person as p 
left join fetch p.vacations as v 
where v.id is null or  v.startDate between '2011-07-01' and '2011-07-30'
```

or maybe (I'm not really sure if this will work)

```
select distinct p from Person as p 
left join fetch p.vacations as v 
where v is null or v.startDate between '2011-07-01' and '2011-07-30'
```

Comment: i 've done something like that works but only partially..because if someone has a vacation, but the start date is not in the interval, it will return null , because the vacations side is not null and respect de condition either.